# RMarkdown + scrartcl: Use ###### (6#) to create \minisec{}

Tags: r-markdown

I create an RMarkdown template for my department. It is based on a custom LaTeX class which in turn is based on `scrartcl`.

I would like to use the `\minisec{}` command from `scrartcl`. I know that I can simply put

```
\minisec{This is my minisec}
```

in my RMarkdown template. But for simplicity and consistency, I would prefer to define `######` (6`#`) as `\minisec{}` so that I can use

```
###### This is my minisec
```

instead of the above.

- Is this possible? If yes, how?
- If not, is it possible to redefine `#####` (5`#`)?

Comment: IMO, `6#` is feasible with a Pandoc filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to redefine `#####` (5 `#`) as `\minisec{}` using LaTeX:

Put

```
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\minisec{#1}}
```

at some place in your document. (I placed it in the `template.tex` which I changed anyway. Other possibilities should be `header-includes:` or `in_header:` in the YAML header.